# Remove black bar on Mojave split screen?

Tags: mojave, split-view

I just updated from Sierra to Mojave, and now split screen apps have large, black dividing bar between them.

[image]

Is there a way to remove or shrink that black bar going down the middle of the screen?

Answer (score 2):

The black spacer in-between the two screens is part of the feature.  I don't believe there's any way to remove it or shrink its size.